# python script to verify the entries in curl output

Tags: python, python-requests, pycurl

Im new to python and looking for suggestions on how to achieve the below output. currently i just have a script to fetch the curl reponse. Looking for suggestions to move forward please.

The curl command will give the output as below. from the output, i wanted to make sure whether it has all the 5 entries or not for a host=xx900xxxx? Later the host will be passed as an argument as file(with list of hosts), so output of each hosts will be verified here and results will be printed.

1. An entry for host exists ex: _ref": "superhost/ZG5zLnN1cGxxxxxxxxxxxyOTAwNmMybjM:xx900xxxx
2. 2 entries in DHCP field(dhcp_associated_objects)
3. 2 entries in DNS field(dhcp_associated_objects)

**curl output:**
`$ curl --cert ${CINITCCNAME}/cert.pem --key ${CINITCCNAME}/key.pem -X GET "https://xxxx.c0.ss.com/wapi/v2.11/superhost?_return_fields=name,dhcp_associated_objects,dns_associated_objects&name:=**xx900xxxx**"

[

```
{

    "_ref": "superhost/ZG5zLnN1cGxxxxxxxxxxxyOTAwNmMybjM:xx900xxxx ",

    "dhcp_associated_objects": [

        "fixedaddress/ZG5zLmZpeGVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTA5LjIxOC4xMjEuMC4u:10.109.100.100/default",

        "fixedaddress/ZG5zLmZpeGVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxuODkuMTUzLjU5LjAuLg:10.89.100.100/default"

    ],

    "dns_associated_objects": [

        "record:host/ZG5zLmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0LmNvbS5tcy5jMC5vb2IucnI5MDA2YzJuMw:xx900xxxx.ccob.c0.ss.com/default",

        "record:host/ZG5zLmhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmNvbS5tcy5jMC5ub2Rlcy5ycjkwMDZjMm4z:xx900xxxx.nodes.c0.ss.com/default"

    ],

    "name": "xx900xxxx"

}
```

]`

Comment: Are you saying that curl is emitting JSON in the format that you've shown? If so, then just use Python's json module to load the data then use get() on each of the three keys to validate their existence and values

Comment: No, i need to validate the curl output has the required entries or not as below?

An entry for host exists ex: _ref": "superhost/ZG5zLnN1cGxxxxxxxxxxxyOTAwNmMybjM:xx900xxxx
2 entries in DHCP field(dhcp_associated_objects)
2 entries in DNS field(dhcp_associated_objects)

Comment: Please add to your question the EXACT output you get from the curl command and also explain what the JSON data is about

Comment: Thats the complete output.This is the data from infoblox for a host about network details.

Comment: So the output is JSON and therefore my previous suggestions apply

Comment: Thanks DarkKnight. How does the syntax needs to be to filter each fields/key? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Any suggestions on the syntax please?